# Is async_connect really asynchronous under GNU/Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, boost, block, boost-asio

I wanted to check whether `Boost Asio` really performs an asynchronous connect or not. According to [the diagrams corresponding to the asynchronous calls](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/basics.html) published in `Asio`'s basics, the operation is started when the `io_service` signals the operating system, and therefore I understand that right after executing the `async.connect` instruction the system attempts to perform that connection.

What I have understood is, if you don't call `run` you just miss the results, but the operations are —probably— completed. So I tried that creating a dummy server with `nc -l -p 9000` and then using the code attached below.

With a debugger, I have gone statement by statement and I have stopped right before the `run` call to the `io_service`. In the server, nothing happens. Nothing about the connect —this is obvious as the dummy server does not tell you about it— nor the `async_write`.

Immediately after calling the `run` function the corresponding messages pop up on the server side. I have been asking on `Boost`'s IRC channel and after showing my `strace`, a really clever person told me that it probably is because the socket is not ready until `run` is called. Apparently, this does not happen on Windows.

Does that this mean that asynchronous is not really asynchronous under GNU/Linux operating systems? Does this mean that the diagram showed in the website does not correspond to GNU/Linux environments?

**NOTE about "is not really asynchronous"**: Yes, it does not block the call and therefore the thread keeps running and doing things, but I mean *asynchronous* by starting the operations right after they have been executed.

Thank you very much indeed in advance.

**The code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

void connect_handler(const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
    if(error)
    {
        std::cout << error.message() << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Successfully connected!" << std::endl;
    }
}

void write_handler(const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
    if(error)
    {
        std::cout << error.message() << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Yes, we wrote!" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(io_service);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint(
        boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("127.0.0.1"), 9000);

    socket.async_connect(endpoint, connect_handler);

    std::string hello_world("Hello World!");
    boost::asio::async_write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(hello_world.c_str(), 
        hello_world.size()), boost::bind(write_handler, 
                                boost::asio::placeholders::error));

    io_service.run();
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

**My strace**

```
futex(0x7f44cd0ca03c, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7f44cd0ca048, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
eventfd2(0, O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC)       = 3
epoll_create1(EPOLL_CLOEXEC)            = 4
timerfd_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, TFD_CLOEXEC) = 5
epoll_ctl(4, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 3, {EPOLLIN|EPOLLERR|EPOLLET, {u32=37842600, u64=37842600}}) = 0
write(3, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)         = 8
epoll_ctl(4, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 5, {EPOLLIN|EPOLLERR, {u32=37842612, u64=37842612}}) = 0
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP) = 6
epoll_ctl(4, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 6, {EPOLLIN|EPOLLPRI|EPOLLERR|EPOLLHUP|EPOLLET, {u32=37842704, u64=37842704}}) = 0
ioctl(6, FIONBIO, [1])                  = 0
connect(6, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(9000), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = -1 EINPROGRESS (Operation now in progress)
epoll_ctl(4, EPOLL_CTL_MOD, 6, {EPOLLIN|EPOLLPRI|EPOLLOUT|EPOLLERR|EPOLLHUP|EPOLLET, {u32=37842704, u64=37842704}}) = 0
epoll_wait(4, {{EPOLLIN, {u32=37842600, u64=37842600}}, {EPOLLOUT, {u32=37842704, u64=37842704}}}, 128, -1) = 2
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 0)    = 1 ([{fd=6, revents=POLLOUT}])
getsockopt(6, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
sendmsg(6, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"Hello World!", 12}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 12
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0600, st_rdev=makedev(136, 5), ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f44cd933000
write(1, "Successfully connected!\n", 24Successfully connected!
) = 24
epoll_wait(4, {}, 128, 0)               = 0
write(1, "Yes, we wrote!\n", 15Yes, we wrote!
)        = 15
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Comment: "starting the operations right after they have been executed" is not a standard meaning of "asynchronous". You might want to read [the boost.asio rationale page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/rationale.html), which describes what the library is for.

Comment: Thank you, @Sneftel, thanks for answering. I read at that page, specially the _"Boost.Asio provides the tools to manage these long running operations, without requiring programs to use concurrency models based on threads and explicit locking."_ part. However, the diagram I linked states —if I understood correctly— that the signal to connect is sent right after executing the `connect` statement. That is the part that confuses me the most.

Comment: Ah, I see the issue. I'll answer more at length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A weird thing about boost.asio -- not unique to it, but generally different from OS-specific asynchronous networking frameworks -- is that it does not rely on auxiliary threads. That has a number of important consequences, which can be boiled down to this: boost.asio is NOT for doing things in the background. Rather, it is for doing *multiple* things in the *foreground*.

`io_service::run()` is the "hub" of boost.asio, and a single-threaded program using boost.asio should expect to spend most of its time waiting inside `io_service::run()`, or executing a completion handler called by it. Depending on the OS-specific internal implementation, it might or might not be possible to have particular asynchronous operations running before that function gets called, which is why calling it is basically the first thing you do once you've kicked off your initial asynchronous requests.

Think of `async_connect` as "arming" your io_service with an asynchronous operation. The actual asynchrony happens during `io_service::run()`. In fact, calling `async_connect` followed immediately by `async_write` is a weird thing to do, and I'm a little surprised that it works. Ordinarily, you'd execute (or, rather, "arm") the `async_write` from within the `connect_handler`, because it's only at that point that you have a connected socket.

Comment: Thanks @Sneftel. Yes, the `async_write` is in a really weird spot, but I did it on purpose so as to see if the `connect` and the `write` were triggered "independently" before the `run` function was called. I am also surprised that it worked, to be honest. Anyway, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: The underlying OS operation _may_ occur within the initiating function (`async_*`) as long as the underlying OS operation does not block.  If the underlying operation would block, it will be added to the reactor and serviced by running the `io_service`.  In certain circumstances, this behavior allows `async_write` immediately following an `async_connect` to succeed. /cc @StrikeTeam